# pytorch не компилируется

Tags: python, pytorch

```
    [Running] python -u "c:\Users\IGOR\Desktop\py\project.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\IGOR\Desktop\py\project.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\IGOR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: �� ������� ��������� ���������.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.164 seconds
```

не могу понять почему не компилируется код

Answer (score 0):

Была аналогичная проблема, оказалось, версия cuda на компьютере не соответствовала заданной при инсталляции pytorch. Решилось перестановкой последнего, с аккуратным подбором параметра cudatoolkit.